# Jest: Get state from component that uses Material-UI

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs

I'm new to Jest and I just want to get the state from a component I have. I can get the state if the component is not using material-ui and is not exported with 'withStyles'. But when I export the component with 'withStyles' it suddenly doesn't work.

component:

```
import React from 'react';
import { withStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';

//CSS styles
const styles = {
    root: {
      marginTop:25,
    },
  };

class Test extends React.Component{
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state={
            test: 'test'
        }
    }
    render(){
        const {classes} = this.props;
        return(
            <p className={classes.root}>test</p>
        )
    }
}

export default withStyles(styles)(Test);
```

Test:

```
test('Get state', () => {
  const wrapper = mount(<Test classes={{}}/>);
  expect(wrapper.state('test')).toEqual('test')
})
```

I read material-ui documentation and saw that they also provide a way of testing. But even when im using their implementation it doesn't work.

Material-UI test:

```
describe('<Test />', () => {
let shallow;

beforeEach(() => {
  shallow = createShallow();
});

 it('get state', () => {
   const wrapper = shallow(<Test/>);
   expect(wrapper.state('test')).toEqual('test')
 });
});
```

I keep getting the error:

> TypeError: ShallowWrapper::state("test") requires that `state` not be `null` or `undefined`

Anyone know what i'm doing wrong?

Comment: the styles, you are passing to the `withStyles` API should be a function If I'm not wrong which should return a style object, can you try doing this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a workaround, don't know if this is the proper way. But you could export your own class and than import the class in your test file and then you will be able to get the state.

New component:

```
import React from 'react';
import { withStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';

//CSS styles
const styles = {
    root: {
      marginTop:25,
    },
  };

export class Test extends React.Component{
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state={
            test: 'test'
        }
    }
    render(){
        const {classes} = this.props;
        return(
            <p className={classes.root}>test</p>
        )
    }
}

export default withStyles(styles)(Test);
```

New test:

```
import {Test} from '../components/TestApp';

test('Get state', () => {
  const wrapper = mount(<Test classes={{}}/>);
  expect(wrapper.state('test')).toEqual('test')
})
```

Don't forget to add `classes={{}}` or else jest will complain that it doesn't recognize your className's you define in the component.

Answer (score 0):

What if you export another version of your class component without using the `withStyles()` wrapper in it, for testing purposes.

such like: `export const TestComponent = new Text();`
may import it as: `import { TestComponent } from './path';`

Answer (score 0):

After a lot of iteration, I found a working solution for me.

```
import React from 'react'
import { shallow, mount } from 'enzyme'
import { unwrap } from '@material-ui/core/test-utils'
import Component from 'path'

const UnwrappedComponent = unwrap(Component);

it('with shallow", () => {
   const wrapper = shallow(<UnwrappedComponent classes={{}} />)
})

it("with mount", () => {
  const wrapper = mount(<UnwrappedComponent classes={{}} />)
})
```